# Angular 2 TypeScript, how do I correctly throw an error?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

Can anyone advise how I can throw custom errors Angular 2 using TypeScript?

My error handling class successfully intercepts errors so I can send them to an endpoint to keep track of things that go wrong and with what frequency.

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export default class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  handleError(error) {
    console.error('Custom error handling...');
    console.error(error);
    // do stuff with error
  }
}
```

This has also been imported in my app.module file.

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import MyErrorHandler from './my-error-handler';
```

and added to it's providers

```
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }]
```

But can anyone tell me how I can throw an error from one of my util services when receiving an invalid value that will subsequently be caught by this class?